# Rename using batch file folders with dot

Tags: batch-file

I have a lot of folders and files with the same prefix and at the end of the perfix there is a dot, for example :
ProjectName.Data

I failed to rename using batch file.
I want to rename from "ProjectName.*" to user input (which defines the actuallty project name, and save the characters after the dot)
for example. if the input is "newProject", that from ProjectName.Data --> newProject.Data

I wrote:

```
@echo off

echo What is your project name?

set /p PROJECTNAME=

for /r %%j in (ProjectName.*) do ren "%%j" "%PROJECTNAME%.*"
```

What is the problem?

Comment: How are you defining `%PROJECTNAME%` in your script?

Comment: Yes, like this: set /p PROJECTNAME=

Comment: Are the files actually named *LITERALLY* `projectname.*` or are they actually named `<theprojectnameIinputted>.*` ?

Comment: The files and folders actullay name ProjectName.* The problem with the rename folders and not rename files.

Comment: Use `for /d /r` to select directories. The `ren` statement must be on the same physical line as the `do`

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work for me. I want to change  to the input and save the characters after the projectName, for example for ProjectName.Data (if the input is newProject) than to newProject.Data

Comment: Have you tried `ren "%%j" "%PROJECTNAME%%%~xj"` ?

Comment: You say files and folders. Does your folders also have the same format of `PREFIX.SUFFIX`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /d /r %%j in (ProjectName.*) DO ren "%%j" "%PROJECTNAME%%%~xj"
```

worked for me.